# Volley throws onErrorResponse by default

Tags: android, json, android-volley

```
 JsonObjectRequest TweetReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,URL1,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    //hidePDialog();

                    SharedPreferences Tempx = getSharedPreferences("ActivitySession", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edx = Tempx.edit();
                    edx.putString("GSON_FEED", response.toString());
                    Log.d("WORKING RESPONSE:::::", response.toString());
                    edx.apply();

                    Gson gson = new Gson();


                    MainPojo main = gson.fromJson( Tempx.getString("GSON_FEED","") , MainPojo.class);

                    statusX = main.getStatuses();
                    for (Status result : statusX) {

                        Log.w("LOKLAK:::",""+result.getUser().getName());

                    }

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            //JsonArray jArray = parser.parse(Tempx.getString("GSON_FEED","")).getAsJsonArray();

            SharedPreferences Tempx = getSharedPreferences("ActivitySession", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            MainPojo main = gson.fromJson( Tempx.getString("GSON_FEED","") , MainPojo.class);

            statusX = main.getStatuses();
            for (Status result : statusX) {

                Log.w("LOKLAK:::",""+result.getUser().getName());

            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            VolleyLog.d("EDUKNOW::::", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Trying to store JSON Objects, however whenever I execute, Volley automatically executes `onErrorResponse()` , what is causing this?

Comment: can you show the error in the log?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in onErrorResponse to check the error:

```
try{
    Log.e("myerror","deal first",e);
    Log.e("myerror","deal success"+new String(error.networkResponse.data,"utf-8"));
}catch (Throwable e){
    Log.e("myerror","deal fail",e);
}
```

Comment: `deal fail
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'byte[] com.android.volley.NetworkResponse.data' on a null object reference`